# Numerically solving a system of ODEs in R with a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve a series of equations using deSolve in R. I wish to list the equations using for loop but having trouble doing so.
The system is as follows:

X_i' = a X_i+1 - (b+c) X_i

X_k' = 2c (X_1+ ... + X_k) - (b+c) X_k

This is how I tried to write it:

```
library(deSolve)
ode_func <- function(t, state, parms){
with(as.list(c(state, parms)),{

#rate of change
for (i in 1:k-1) {
dX[i] <-  a * X[i+1] - (b + c) * X[i]
dX[k] <-  2 * c * sum(X[i]) - (b + c) * X[k]

#return the rate of change
list(c(dX[i], dX[k])) } }) }

k=10
#initial conditions
state <- c(rep(0, k-1), 1e4)
times=seq(0,500,1)

sol_ode <- ode(y= state, times=times, func = ode_func,
           parms = list(a= 0.01, b= 0.01, alpha = 0.01))
```

I get and error saying that 'object X not found'. I have used deSolve many times successfully but had bever had to use for loop. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: This is because you have not defined X[i+1] anywhere. check your line `dX[i] <-  a * X[i+1] - (b + c) * X[i]` inside for loop, X[i+1] is not defined anywhere and hence the error

Comment: @Hardikgupta I dont think that's true. I think its because of the state variable. My state shoud ideally look like:
state <- c(X[1] = 0, X[2] = 0 .... X[k-1] = 0, X[k]=1e4)

But ts doesnt look like that currently. I have zero experience of writing for loops in R. Don't know how to achieve that